# Recoverable Error: Method ::__toString() must return a string value

Tags: php, magento

When i load product page, it display error in system log file like this..

```
2013-03-12T10:28:56+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Method SM_Vendors_Model_Mysql4_Vendor_Collection::__toString() must return a string value  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\SM\Vendors\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Render\Vendor.php on line 21
```

My code is like..

app\code\local\SM\Vendors\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Render\vendor.php

```
class SM_Vendors_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Render_Vendor extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
 public function getElementHtml()
 {
 $vendorCollection = $this->getVendorCollection(); //line#21
 }

 public function getVendorCollection()
 {
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smvendors/vendor_collection')->__toString();
  return $collection;
 }
}
```

app\code\local\SM\Vendors\Model\Mysql4\Vendor\Collection.php

```
class SM_Vendors_Model_Mysql4_Vendor_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract 
{
 public function _construct() 
 {
  parent::_construct();
  $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
 }
 public function __toString()
 {
    return $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
 }
}
```

I want to solve this type of error display in system log file in magento.If you know then please kindly reply.

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->_init('smvendors/vendor'));`. What's there?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that  $this->_init('smvendors/vendor'); returns a string. or return something else which is a string in __toString at:

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have incorrect usage of `__toString()` method in your code.
It seems that here this method is used to get collection, not a string.

```
public function getVendorCollection()
 {
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smvendors/vendor_collection')->__toString();
  return $collection;
 }
```

It is incorrect and a very bad idea.
You need to refactor your code, or you will never get rid of this warning.

**What to do**

For example you could do the following.. 
Rename `__toString` method to `getCollection` and replace the places where `_toString` was used with `getCollection`.
Replace until the message in the log will not disappear.

Read more here about your problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

**So here is fixed code:**

```
class SM_Vendors_Model_Mysql4_Vendor_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract 
{
 public function _construct() 
 {
  parent::_construct();
  $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
 }
 public function getCollection()
 {
    return $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
 }

 public function __toString()
 {
    return $this->_init('smvendors/vendor');
 }

}
```

And second class...

```
class SM_Vendors_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Render_Vendor extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
 public function getElementHtml()
 {
 $vendorCollection = $this->getVendorCollection(); //line#21
 }

 public function getVendorCollection()
 {
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smvendors/vendor_collection')->getCollection();
  return $collection;
 }
}
```

Comment: i already try this but it return 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' for further code that we use after line#21.

Comment: It display error like this '2013-03-12T11:55:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Object of class SM_Vendors_Model_Mysql4_Vendor_Collection could not be converted to string  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\SM\Vendors\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Render\Vendor.php on line 21'.

Comment: Try now (I just restored __toString() method)... It seems to be needed for admin panel..

Comment: now it display '2013-03-12T12:06:10+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Method SM_Vendors_Model_Mysql4_Vendor_Collection::__toString() must return a string value  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\SM\Vendors\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Render\Vendor.php on line 21'. I want to clean my system log file.